# code source of Fork(), Diagram process

Tags: unix, process, fork, pid

i have this Diagram of process, i have to do the code source!!!
please check if its correct

[image]

the is the my solution for

a)

```
           #include <unistd.h>
             int main(void) {
             int i;
          for (i= 0; i < 3; i++)
          {
            if(!fork()) 
             break;
                      }

         while(wait(NULL) !==-1);//to avoid the appearance of zombies processes??
```

the second solution b):

```
           #include <unistd.h>
             int main(void) {
             int i,pid;
            for(i=0; i<3;i++)
             {
              pid=fork();
             if (pid>0)
               break;
                       }
            while(wait(NULL)!=-1);
```

PS:Also i have to includ the comment to indicate where i have to include the"" exec"" that will run each of the children!?

Comment: Why so many "!" and "?" ? Is there something wrong with your keyboard ?

Comment: They are both wrong. In both versions the child process will call wait(), which is not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

In both programs, you need to rationalize the indentation, and include a missing close brace at the end.

Solution (a) is more or less correct.  We can argue about the choice of `wait()` vs `waitpid()`, and you should `#include <sys/wait.h>` to declare the waiting function you use.  You haven't shown where you would do the `exec()`, which means we can't say whether you'd run into issues with child processes waiting on zero children - which is ungainly but doesn't otherwise affect correctness.  (Personally, I'd write `if (fork() == 0)` because I think it is clearer than `!fork()`, especially since a return value of 0 means the process forked successfully, whereas `!fork()` reads 'not fork' which could rather easily mean 'did not fork'.

Solution (b) is also more or less correct, except the position of the `exec()` will be different, and if the `fork()` fails, you will execute the loop a bit longer than you should, but again it is unlikely to be a major problem.  The main issue will be 'how does a process tell whether it is the original or one of the children'?  You haven't shown the control information that will be needed to distinguish between the original process and the various children.  Also, if you have pipes to set up or anything, that is not shown.